# Understanding Border's properties

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, border, mousemove

I have a `Border` (contains a `Canvas` inside) defined as follows where I want to dynamic show the position of mouse when moving over the `Canvas`:

**In `.xmal`:**

```
<Border x:Name="cwgLayoutDesignBorder" BorderThickness="0"
        Width="600" Height="800" BorderBrush="Yellow">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="linecontrol">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas  Background="Green" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas>
                    ... 
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

**In `.cs`:**

```
private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = e.GetPosition(linecontrol);

    this.Title = "(" + Convert.ToInt32(p.X) + ", " + Convert.ToInt32(p.Y) + ")";
}
```

I found that the position returned by the mouse turned out to be: `x` in `[0, 600]` and `y` in `[1, 800]`. However, given my definition, I thought the result should be `[0, 599]` and `y` in `[0, 799]` instead. Why are they inconsistent? Or how should I get the correct position of the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `x[0,599]` and `y[0,799]`. If you try and draw a pixel at `0,0` it will be the top left pixel and if you draw at `600,800` it will draw outside the Canvas. Draw a simple 50x50 canvas and run this against it to see:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 51; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 51; y++)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.White,
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            Width=1,
            Height=1
        };

        if (x == 0 & y == 0)
        {
            rect.Stroke = Brushes.LimeGreen;
        }

        if (x == 50 & y == 50)
        {
            rect.Stroke = Brushes.LimeGreen;
        }

        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);
        youCanvasNameHere.Children.Add(rect);
    }
}
```

You might need to use `magnify.exe` to see it though.

Comment: Thanks. But why did I get `x in [0, 600]` and `y in [1, 800]`?

Comment: I got 0,600 0,800 form your sample code as well, the actual canvas pixels are the 0,599 0,799   if you magnify and look you'll see the 600 and 800 are actually off the edge of the canvas.

Comment: But I get 0,50 x 0,50 with the same experiment on an empty window with just a canvas of 50x50, while the pixels are only populating 0,49 x 0,49; so i don't think it has anything to do with how your canvas is getting it's size and is just the way GetPosition works. /shrug

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the correct mouse position and using the correct method to do so. If your `Border` element has a `Width` of `600` and its `Height` is set to `800`, then any contained UI element will inherit those *same values*. That means that your `linecontrol ItemsControl` element will also be `600`x`800`. Only if your `Border.BorderThickness` or `Border.Padding` (or other size changing property) is set to a positive value will the size of the contained control change.

Even then, if your `Border.BorderThickness` property was set to `1`, then your `ItemsControl.Width` would be `598` and not `599`, so I suspect that you may have misread your values. I used *your* code to run *your* experiment and found that `Width` and `Height` values went from `0` to `600` and `0` to `800` respectively. So, either you've read your values incorrectly, or you need to edit your question to provide [*all relevant code required to successfully reproduce your problem*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Shouldn't them be 0 to 599 and 0 to 799 respectively?

Comment: Try it yourself in a new project with the code that you showed.

Comment: I will do it. Thanks.